# NSURLSession error handling

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, afnetworking

Using Swift and NSURLSession. The NSError localizedDescription I get is very generic when I don't have internet connection (manually turned off wifi/cell network). It says "*The operation couldn’t be completed.*"

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
```

I'm looking for a more specific message to send to the user. I enabled a breakpoint and inspected all objects but can't find anything good.

Prior to swift I was using AFNetworking with objective C:

```
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
```

The error messages I would get here were very descriptive, something like "*the internet connection appears to be offline*"

Comment: You've to handle internet errors by yourself. `AFNetworking` implements `Reachability` by itself, that's why their errors are more descriptive and context aware. Additionally, you could use `AFNetworking` in your swift project, like described here. [AFNetworking Integrate Swift](https://medium.com/@aommiez/afnetwork-integrate-swfit-80514b545b40)

Comment: hmm was trying to break away from the dependency of external libraries. But looks like I'll use alamo fire (AFNetworking version of Swift) then https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: A minor clarification: I agree that libraries like Alamofire and AFNetworking offer richer error handling, but it's because they're checking for things we otherwise have to manually check for (e.g. correct `Content-Type`, the `statusCode` of the `NSHTTPURLResponse`, etc.). This has nothing to do with the fact that AFNetworking offers (but does not use, by default) Reachability. For general network errors, they simply return the same `NSError` objects we get when we do this manually ourselves.

Answer (score 34):

You can consider the `code` of the [`URLError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlerror/):

```swift
if let error = error as? URLError, error.code == .notConnectedToInternet {
    ...
}
```

---

You can also cast to `NSError` and look at the `code` and `domain`, e.g.,

```swift
if let error = error as? NSError, error.domain == NSURLErrorDomain, error.code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet {
    print("not connected")
}
```

---

Also, search for `NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet` by pressing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and then, you'll be taken to the relevant header (`NSURLError.h`). Personally for this sort of stuff, I tend to trust the headers a little more than the documentation. If you do this search when working with Objective-C, you'll even see cross reference to `CFURLError` codes (which you can either <kbd>command</kbd>-click on or <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and search for `kCFURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet`), and if you explore those, you'll actually see the numeric values associated with these constants.

Comment: this is helpful. Is there a complete list that specifies all error codes/domains and their descriptions?

Comment: For `NSURLErrorDomain` codes, I'd suggest looking at the headers. See above. I don't think the other domains are relevant here.

Comment: This is the NSUrlError domain enumeration [https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlerror](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlerror)

Comment: @Rob Now the error type has become 'Error' and that doesn't have the members 'domain' and 'code'... How to do the same?

Comment: No, I think you'll find although the parameter is an `Error`, it really is a `NSError`. So you can do `if let error = error as? NSError` in Swift 3, as shown in my revised answer.

Comment: FYI I think the latest page for these is: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlerror

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4**

```
if let error = error as NSError?, error.domain == NSURLErrorDomain && error.code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet {
      //not connected
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in 
if error == nil {
   //all ok do what you want to do
} else {
   let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Put your error message here", preferredStyle: .Alert)

   let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
                      }
   alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
   self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true)
}
})
```

This implementation shows an alert to the user that something went wrong. You can handle the error as you like (for example by  retrying the request without annoying the user with an alert).
`UIAlertController` is iOS 8 only. If you want to support iOS 7 show a `UIAlertView`.

Answer (score 0):

NSURLSession only returns NSError for client side errors, you also have to check for server side errors by looking at the NSURLResponse's status code.

```
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

    BOOL connectionError = !!error;//Error on client side (e.g. lost connection)
    BOOL serverError = ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)response).statusCode != 200;//Error on server side (e.g. bad data)
            
    BOOL failed = connectionError || serverError;

    if (failed) {
        //was failure, handle error.
        return;
    }

    //else, was success, proceed.

}];
```

Comment: Note: Depending on your back end, you may get success status codes beyond generic '200'. See here for full list that NSURLSessions supports: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean the `operation.responseString` for specific error response from backend?
I just found it yesterday, check this out in failure block of `AFHTTPSessionManager` request

```
NSError *underError = error.userInfo[@"NSUnderlyingError"];
NSData *responseData = underError.userInfo[@"com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data"];
```

Here's [the question I asked at AFN/Github](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/3232). Hope it'll be helpful.